# ext.js is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.get('mb1').on('click', function(e) {
        Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?', showResult);
});
function showResult() {
    Ext.example.msg('test');
</script>

<div>
<asp:Button ID="mb1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

I got error message "ext is undefined". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you included all the necessary script files?

Answer (score 8):

You have to include the js file like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs.js"></script>
```

before using any of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

you should download the extjs framework from the site itself and host it locally if you can. http://extjs.com

Comment: Download the SDK and read the file INCLUDE_ORDER.txt. Also see the example html files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it possible that you used "`ext`" somewhere instead of "`Ext`" (wrong capitalization)?
2. you don't seem to be closing your functions with "`}`"

Once you get Ext working, you'll probably want to use the button's client ID instead of the code-behind ID:

```
...
Ext.get('<%=mb1.ClientID%>').on('click', function(e) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Include below all three file in your file 
ext-all.css,ext-base.js,ext-all-debug.js

Comment: I added  ext-base.js,ext-all-debug.js pages.  But i have ext-all.js page only. i dont have  ext-all.css page .

Can u send that file or any path to download to that file

Comment: I have added ext-all.css pages also. but still i got same error